# Show that the square of determinant on LHS is equal to the determinant on RHS.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If $\omega$ is one of the imaginary cube roots of unity, show that the square of
$\begin{vmatrix}1&\omega&\omega^2&\omega^3\\
\omega&\omega^2&\omega^3&1\\
\omega^2&\omega^3&1&\omega\\
\omega^3&1&\omega&\omega^2\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}1&1&-2&1\\1&1&1&-2\\-2&1&1&1\\1&-2&1&1\end{vmatrix}$

Hence, show that the value of the determinant on the left is $3√-3$ .

**What I've tried :**

I'd multiplied the determinant on left 2 times and I got the following determinant and I don't know how to get the desired determinant from here
$\begin{vmatrix}1&1&\omega&1\\
1&1&1&-2\\
-2&1&1&1\\
1&-2\omega&1&-2\omega\end{vmatrix}$

Comment: Explain how you got $\omega$ in the top row of the determinant you calculated from $\omega^2+\omega^4+\omega^2+\omega^4$.

Comment: By simple determinant multiplication but sorry I am not master at latex so that I cannot explain it all its very difficult to represent it using latex that's why 

Comment: Oops my mistake while multiplying determinants i got it

Comment: If you resolved it, etiquette would be to either post a self-answer or remove the question.